# Google Nexus 6P Stuck In Boot Mode on Google Screen

Tags: boot-loop, nexus-6p

Is there a fix for the Google Nexus 6p Stuck In Boot Mode on Google Screen issue?

A couple days after I got an Android OTA update for Nougat from Google, the phone got switched off and it’s not switching on itself. When I try to start the phone, only the Google Logo appears for 5 seconds and then disappears and repeats the same.

The Google logo flashes as if to start up, going black and repeating. Have tried holding on/off for varying times – won’t turn on or off. Tried Reboot Reloader – starts flashing Google again Tried Recovery mode – starts flashing Google again. I have Taken the phone off the charger and I am Past the warranty period.

When I try:

- Turn off the phone
- Hold the volume down button and Power button simultaneously until the device switches on.
- You should see “Start” with an arrow
- Tap volume down twice and the power button to enter Recovery Mode
- Hold the power button then press and release the volume up button
- Use the volume buttons to select wipe data/factory reset
- Choose “Yes – erase all data” with the power button

I get an error

Comment: What bootloop issue? What did you do and what happened?

Comment: I can't believe your post was downvoted. Stackexchange has turned to poison. I found your information helpful although it did not solve my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to send it back for the repairs. Another alternative is to reinstall the OS although is a topic in itself (XDA Developers Forum is the best place to find an answer on how to do that for your version of OS).

I have the same issue with Nexus 5X which I sent for the repairs, less hassle.